# Combined su and screen at startup

Tags: boot, gnu-screen, startup, su

I want to start a long running custom script at boot.
The script must run under a specific username.
So far I have successfully used the screen command and switched to the user in the custom script. But I rather have the screen command run under that user so that I can later login to that user and resume the screen.

This one does work when run as root in the console but it does not work as a line in a startup script.

su -c "screen -S sessionname -d -m /path/cot/bash/script" username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under GNU/Linux at boot, you should not use `su` (as [it depends on PAM/dbus](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825995#15), which may not be available yet), but `runuser`:

```
runuser username -l -c "screen -S sessionname -d -m /path/to/bash/script"
```

When using `runuser` followed by the user name, the syntax is the same as `su`.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, I should have used the  -l flag:

```
su -l -c "screen -S sessionname -d -m /path/to/bash/script" username
```